# Did this device really exist in the 19th century?

Tags: apostle

In Apostle (2018), Quinn frames Jeremy for Ffion's murder and uses a "purification" ritual to murder him with a hand crank in front of the Islanders. Did the device really exist in that era? Or was it just a made up thing for the movie only?

Any historical evidence shared will be really helpful.

Comment: An image here would be useful but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank_(mechanism)

Comment: @Paulie_D I didn't put an image because it is graphic in nature.

Comment: If an image is needed but is graphic in nature, you can hide it in a spoiler tag and put in some kind of content warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the device you are asking about is the one visible in the lower corner of this image:

[image]

It appears similar to the 19th century hand cranked drill press available for sale at: [Chairish](https://www.chairish.com/product/466172/19th-century-cast-iron-antique-blacksmith-drill-press).

[image]